# How do I check if subgroups of a character column in R are different?

Tags: r, difference

I have some columns of characters such as:

```
V1 V2 group
B  C  1
B  C  1
B  C  1
A  C  2
A  A  2
A  A  2
```

in a data frame (call it df) in R which are also grouped by a factor with 2 levels 1 and 2, and I wanted to use 
'by' or 'lapply' to see if I could work out which column(s) had a corresponding group structure which is given by group. In this case, the answer would be column V1.

I was thinking something like

```
by(df, df$group,...)
```

but wasn't quite sure how to implement this. I've also seen the 'identical' function but didn't know if the opposite was available?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be

```
 sapply(df[,1:2], function(x) all(as.numeric(factor(x, 
                             levels=unique(x)))==df$group))
 # V1    V2 
#TRUE FALSE
```

Or  for this example

```
!colSums((df[,1:2]=='A')+1!=df$group)
 # V1    V2 
 #TRUE FALSE
```

Or you could use

```
!rowSums(aggregate(.~ group, df, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))[,-1]!=1)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```